import neasted xml file to multiple tables
I am new to databricks and want to import a neasted xml into multiple tables.
I have a xml and a xsd which you can find below.
Until now I have done following steps:
Python Code
Import XML to df:
# Files
xml_file: str = "/FileStore/tables/demo.xml"
xsd_file: str = "/FileStore/tables/demo.xsd"

# Read XML file with XSD validation
df = spark.read \
    .format("xml") \
    .option("rowTag", "transactions") \
    .option("attributePrefix", "") \
    .option("rowValidationXSDPath", xsd_file) \
    .load(xml_file)

# Display the DataFrame
df.display()

df for transactions:
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id, col

transactions_df = df.select(
    monotonically_increasing_id().alias("transaction_id"),
    "day",
    "art",
    "version",
    col("site.site_id").alias("site_id"),
    col("footer.tran_count").alias("tran_count")
)

transactions_df.display()

This works, but I would like to have the following three target tables with artificial primary key and foreign key, so that I can join them later.
So I need DataFrames for trans and data_detail, too.
Table 1: transactions
transaction_id: artificial primary key



transaction_id
day
art
version
site_id
tran_count




1
1000
lo
1
20
3



Table 2: trans
transaction_id: foreign key to transactions.transaction_id
trans_id: artificial primary



transaction_id
trans_id
number
pro
lib
nr
at
bt
ct




1
1
1234567
p1
l1
12345-1234567
123
1
120


1
2
2345678
p2
l2
12345-2345678
456
1
240


1
3
3456789
p3
l3
12345-3456789
789
1
360



Table 3: data_detail
trans_id: foreign key to trans.trans_id
detail_id: artificial primary key



trans_id
detail_id
data_detail_id
type
class




1
1
0
5
10


1
2
1
6
11


2
3
0
7
20


2
4
1
8
21


3
5
0
9
30


3
6
1
10
31



xsd-file (demo.xsd)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="transactions">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="site"/>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="trans"/>
        <xs:element ref="footer"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="day" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:attribute name="art" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:attribute name="version" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="site">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="site_id" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="trans">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element ref="number"/>
        <xs:element ref="meta"/>
        <xs:element ref="details"/>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="footer">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="tran_count" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="number" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="meta">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="pro"/>
        <xs:element ref="lib"/>
        <xs:element ref="nr"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="pro" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="lib" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="nr" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="details">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="header"/>
        <xs:element ref="data"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="header">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="at"/>
        <xs:element ref="bt"/>
        <xs:element ref="ct"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="at" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="bt" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="ct" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="data_detail"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="data_detail">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="typ"/>
        <xs:element ref="class"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="detail_id" use="required" type="xs:integer"/> 
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="typ" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="class" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:schema>

xml-file (demo.xml)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transactions day="1000" art="lo" version="1">
<site site_id="20"/>
<trans>
  <number>1234567</number>
  <meta>
    <pro>p1</pro>
    <lib>l1</lib>
    <nr>12345-1234567</nr>
  </meta>
  <details>
    <header>
      <at>123</at>
      <bt>1</bt>
      <ct>120</ct>
    </header>
    <data>
        <data_detail detail_id="0">
          <typ>5</typ>
          <class>10</class>
        </data_detail>
        <data_detail detail_id="1">
          <typ>6</typ>
          <class>11</class>
        </data_detail>
    </data>
  </details>
</trans>
<trans>
  <number>2345678</number>
  <meta>
    <pro>p2</pro>
    <lib>l2</lib>
    <nr>12345-2345678</nr>
  </meta>
  <details>
    <header>
      <at>456</at>
      <bt>1</bt>
      <ct>240</ct>
    </header>
    <data>
        <data_detail detail_id="0">
          <typ>7</typ>
          <class>20</class>
        </data_detail>
        <data_detail detail_id="1">
          <typ>8</typ>
          <class>21</class>
        </data_detail>
    </data>
  </details>
</trans>
<trans>
  <number>3456789</number>
  <meta>
    <pro>p3</pro>
    <lib>l3</lib>
    <nr>12345-3456789</nr>
  </meta>
  <details>
    <header>
      <at>789</at>
      <bt>1</bt>
      <ct>360</ct>
    </header>
    <data>
        <data_detail detail_id="0">
          <typ>9</typ>
          <class>30</class>
        </data_detail>
        <data_detail detail_id="1">
          <typ>10</typ>
          <class>31</class>
        </data_detail>
    </data>
  </details>
</trans>
<footer tran_count="3"/>
</transactions>


While I do not know pyspark, I do know about handling nested XML for data frame migration (namely with pandas). For your nuanced needs, consider XSLT, the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. Python's lxml can run XSLT 1.0 transformations.
Specifically, for your use case, have the XSLT transform the original XML to prepare the three elements for your data frame migration: transactions, trans, and detail. Stylesheet can even handle the monotonically increasing IDs by counting siblings! XSD is not needed for this solution especially given we transform original XML. But certainly use XSD to validate original XML prior to XSLT processing.
XSLT (save as .xsl, a special .xml file)
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <data>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::transactions"/>
        <trans>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::trans"/>
        </trans>
        <data_detail>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::data_detail"/>
        </data_detail>
    </data>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="transactions">
    <xsl:copy>
        <transaction_id><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::transaction) + 1"/></transaction_id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <site_id><xsl:value-of select="site/@site_id"/></site_id>
        <transaction_count><xsl:value-of select="count(descendant::trans)"/></transaction_count>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="transactions/@*|data_detail/@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="trans">
    <xsl:copy>
        <transaction_id><xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::transaction/preceding-sibling::transaction) + 1"/></transaction_id>
        <trans_id><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::trans) + 1"/></trans_id>
        <xsl:copy-of select="number|meta/*|header/*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="data_detail">
    <xsl:copy>
        <trans_id><xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::trans/preceding-sibling::trans) + 1"/></trans_id>
        <detail_id><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::data_detail) + 1"/></detail_id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Transformed XML (notice needed elements at root level)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <transactions>
    <transaction_id>1</transaction_id>
    <day>1000</day>
    <art>lo</art>
    <version>1</version>
    <site_id>20</site_id>
    <transaction_count>3</transaction_count>
  </transactions>
  <trans>
    <trans>
      <transaction_id>1</transaction_id>
      <trans_id>1</trans_id>
      <number>1234567</number>
      <pro>p1</pro>
      <lib>l1</lib>
      <nr>12345-1234567</nr>
    </trans>
    <trans>
      <transaction_id>1</transaction_id>
      <trans_id>2</trans_id>
      <number>2345678</number>
      <pro>p2</pro>
      <lib>l2</lib>
      <nr>12345-2345678</nr>
    </trans>
    <trans>
      <transaction_id>1</transaction_id>
      <trans_id>3</trans_id>
      <number>3456789</number>
      <pro>p3</pro>
      <lib>l3</lib>
      <nr>12345-3456789</nr>
    </trans>
  </trans>
  <detail>
    <data_detail>
      <trans_id>1</trans_id>
      <detail_id>1</detail_id>
      <detail_id>0</detail_id>
      <typ>5</typ>
      <class>10</class>
    </data_detail>
    <data_detail>
      <trans_id>1</trans_id>
      <detail_id>2</detail_id>
      <detail_id>1</detail_id>
      <typ>6</typ>
      <class>11</class>
    </data_detail>
    <data_detail>
      <trans_id>2</trans_id>
      <detail_id>1</detail_id>
      <detail_id>0</detail_id>
      <typ>7</typ>
      <class>20</class>
    </data_detail>
    <data_detail>
      <trans_id>2</trans_id>
      <detail_id>2</detail_id>
      <detail_id>1</detail_id>
      <typ>8</typ>
      <class>21</class>
    </data_detail>
    <data_detail>
      <trans_id>3</trans_id>
      <detail_id>1</detail_id>
      <detail_id>0</detail_id>
      <typ>9</typ>
      <class>30</class>
    </data_detail>
    <data_detail>
      <trans_id>3</trans_id>
      <detail_id>2</detail_id>
      <detail_id>1</detail_id>
      <typ>10</typ>
      <class>31</class>
    </data_detail>
  </detail>
</data>

Python
import lxml.etree as lx
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id, col

# FILES
xml_file: str = "/path/to/input.xml"
xsl_file: str = "/path/to/style.xsl"
out_file: str = "/path/to/output.xml"

# TRANSFORM ORIGINAL XML
xml, xsl = lx.parse(xml_file), lx.parse(xsl_file)
transform = lx.XSLT(xsl)
result = transform(xml)
result.write_output(out_file)

# READ IN TRANSFORMED, FLAT XML INTO THREE PYSPARK DATA FRAMES
spark = ...

transformations_df = (
    spark.read
        .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
        .option("rootTag", "data")
        .option("rowTag", "transformations")
        .load(out_file)
)

trans_df = (
    spark.read
        .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
        .option("rootTag", "data")
        .option("rowTag", "trans")
        .load(out_file)
)

data_detail_df = (
    spark.read
        .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
        .option("rootTag", "data")
        .option("rowTag", "data_detail")
        .load(out_file)
)

# ... DATA BRICKS MIGRATION


Or by dictionary comprehension for DRY-er code:
dfs = {
    el: (
        spark.read
            .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
            .option("rootTag", "data")
            .option("rowTag", el)
            .load(out_file)
        )
    for el in ["transformations", "trans", "data_detail"]
}

# ... DATA BRICKS MIGRATION


